# Can Oracle's SQL Translation Framework translate SQL embedded in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Can Oracle's SQL Translation Framework translate SQL queries embedded in PL/SQL blocks?

I have some translation profile and translation in place, if I just put the SQL in, say, SQL Plus, it translates correctly.

But if the SQL is inside PLSQL, like in `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('here')`, or in cursor declaration like `CURSOR mycursor IS SELECT 'HERE'.....`, then there is no translation done.

Comment: Confused...you have PL/SQL and SQL - it doesn't need translated. Are you saying you have a PL/SQL block that's executing T-SQL queries?

The translator ignores pl/sql anon blocks.

But anyways, the framework can handle mixed languages, e.g. stored procedures running T-SQL.

Comment: I was just thinking maybe it would simply translate any SQL as long as the string matches.

Comment: we changed it to ignore sql inside an existing oracle block - for translating that is

Comment: @user1249190 Perhaps DBMS_ADVANCED_REWRITE can work better here?